# R ggplot2 control the legend columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use the `ggplot` command `guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol=3))` to show my discrete categories in three columns in my legend.

But ideally, I would like to

a) **Organise the legend key columns** in a meaningful way (below that would be all negative categories left, 0 alone in the middle and all positive values in the right column)

b) Ideally also have a **column heading** for each column (e.g. "positive", "nothing", "negative")

Currently, as you can see, the columns are simply organised in the order of the factor levels.
Any ideas how to do this?

Many thanks for your help!

```
library(tidyverse)

map_data("world") %>% 
  distinct(region) -> regions
  
set.seed(1)
regions %>% 
  mutate(value = sample(-3:3,rep(nrow(regions)),replace=TRUE),
         value = factor(value)) %>% 
  full_join(map_data("world"),by="region") -> world
  

ggplot(world) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=value)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=3)) + 
  coord_quickmap() + 
  theme_void()+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdBu")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: A quick hack to get the columns to align, you can add empty levels to your factor before and after 0 to force 1 and 2 to the third column. And you'll have to use a `scale_fill_manual` and use NA on those extra levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the `new_scale_fill` function of the `ggnewscale` package.

```
library(ggnewscale)

pal_rdbu <- scales::brewer_pal(palette = "RdBu")(7)

ggplot(world) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=value)) +
  coord_quickmap() + 
  theme_void()+ 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "positive", breaks = 3:1,
                    values=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,pal_rdbu[5:7]))+
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=value)) +
  scale_fill_manual( name = "neutral", breaks = 0,
                     values=c(NA,NA,NA,pal_rdbu[4],NA,NA,NA)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=value)) +
  scale_fill_manual( name = "negative", breaks = -1:-3,
                     values=c(pal_rdbu[1:3],NA,NA,NA,NA)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.direction = 'vertical')
```

[image]